# Select element from XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath

Given the following:

```
declare @samplexml as xml
set @samplexml = '<root><someelement><another /><somethingElse>test</somethingElse></someelement></root>'

select
  @samplexml.value('/root[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

I get the result:

`test`

But I want the result:

`<root><someelement><another /><somethingElse>test</somethingElse></someelement></root>`

How can I select the actual XML element? I also tried:

```
select
  @samplexml.value('/root[1]','XML')
```

But I got the error `The data type 'XML' used in the VALUE method is invalid.`.

Comment: Are you trying to get the full xml given as input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the `.query()` method instead of `.value()` :

```
SELECT @samplexml.query('/root[1]')
```

or

```
SELECT @samplexml.query('.')
```

This returns the element (and its contents) that matches that XPath expression given, and it's returned as `XML` type